# Syntax highlighting for coffeescript in Wing IDE

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, lexer, wing-ide

Does any know of a way to get syntax highlighting for coffeescript files in Wing IDE? I've got it set to highlight as if it were a javascript file, which works alright, but there are a few things it lacks, particularly comments. Has someone written a lexer for this. I'm going to be working with coffeescript for a long while and it would be very helpful to have the highlighting work correctly.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there isn't syntax highlighting support for coffeescript in Wing 4.  It should be in Wing 5, though I don't know when that is out.  I'll take a look also to see if we can add this in Wing 4, although it may not work out due to compatibility of the different code bases involved.

Comment: Thanks. If you are able to add this to wing 4, let me know. I'd love to have it.

Comment: Did anything ever come of this?

Comment: No, sorry, I wasn't able to add it to Wing 4.

Comment: What's the status on coffeescript being added to wing 5? I just upgraded my pro license from wing 4 expecting that support and it's rather disappointing that it's not added yet.

Comment: Sorry, I see that it's broken in our current beta.  I've just fixed it in our sources for the next release (not counting 5.0beta8, which has already been built).